# jQuery XML parsing, two different nodes, same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm using jQuery to parse an XMl file.

The XML file contains the following:

```
<item>
<title> Hello! </title>
<media:title> Hello! </media:title>
</item>
```

I want to parse what's inside the `title`, and when I use

```
var parsedTitle = $item.find("title"); 
console.log(parsedTitle.text()); //output: Hello!Hello!
```

The output will be duplicated, since there are two nodes with the same name.

**How do I choose one of them? let's say I want to parse only the title with the name space**

Comment: `.find()` returns a collection not textContent, [can you reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I updated my question. I'm using `.text()` to get the textContent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parsedTitle = $item.find("title").filter(function () {
    return this.namespaceURI === "http://the/media/namespace/uri/";
});
```

You could also extend jQuery to support namespaces in selectors:

```
$.expr[':'].ns = function (obj, index, meta, stack) {
    return obj.namespaceURI === meta[3];
};
```

and later

```
var parsedTitle = $item.find("title:ns(http://the/media/namespace/uri/)");
```